Loop count up assembly
I'm learning assembly, Small silly question if is possible loop counting up code below;
Is getting time exceeded, perhaps CMP EAX, EBX
With INC EBX
Store values are not beating right when counted
section .data

message db 'Hello, world!', 0x0a

k dd 0

t dd 9

section .text

global _start

mov eax, 0x1

xb:
mov eax, 4 ; system call number for write
mov ebx, 1 ; file descriptor for stdout
mov ecx, k ; address of string to write
mov edx, 13 ; length of string
int 0x80 ; call kernel
mov eax, 1 ; system call number for exit
mov ebx, 0 ; exit code
int 0x80 ; call kernel
_start:
mov eax, k
inc eax
mov [k], eax
mov ebx, 2
cmp eax, ebx
jle xb
cmp eax, ebx
jmp _start

I try some few things!

When you single-step the code in a debugger, what do you see?  This looks like NASM, so mov eax, k puts the address into EAX, which is always much higher than 2.
